# Partition a slide in rmarkdown reveal.js presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js

I would like to break a slide into sections and style each section using `rmarkdown` in a `revealjs` presentation.   The PowerPoint slides below are the general idea I am after. I believe CSS would be the way to go but I am not fluent in CSS and have not been able to find any code chunks as a solution to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** The actual plots and pictures in my example don't matter I care about control and styling over the layout.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandoc divs (i.e. `:::::`, or `:::` etc.) and assign CSS class or id to them and then define css rules for class or id selector in a separate **style.css** file.

**revealjs_presentation.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Layout in RevealJs Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    css: style.css
---

## R Markdown

::::: {style="display: flex;"}

:::: {.column1}

::: {.section1}

**This is section 1**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, urna consequat felis vehicula class ultricies mollis dictumst, aenean non a in donec nulla.

:::

::: {.section2}

**This is section 2**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, urna consequat felis vehicula class ultricies mollis dictumst, aenean non a in donec nulla.


:::

::::

:::: {.column2}

::: {.section3}

**This is section 3**


```{r}
print("This is section 3")
```

:::

::: {.section4}

**This is section 4**

```{r}
print("This is section 4")
```

:::

::::

:::::
````

**style.css**

```
.column1, 
.column2 {
  width: 50%;
}


.section1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: blue;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}

.section2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  margin: 50px 20px 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}


.section3 {
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0 !important;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}

.section4 {
  margin: 50px 20px 0 0 !important;
  background-color: coral;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}

.section3 pre,
.section4 pre {
  background-color: white;
}
```

---

[image: multicolumn layout in revealjs presentation]

---

As a reference read [this section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html#multi-column) from Rmarkdown Cookbook.

Comment: General info: Be careful with the pandoc split, I had to give an extra space after the last `:::::` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define div elements like

```
<div id="NW"></div>
<div id="NE"></div>
<div id="SW"></div>
<div id="SE"></div>
```

and then assign the css you need.

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gcgej/).